# long division acurate answer on dividing long numbers

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, arbitrary-precision, arithmetic

ok but first of all if i have the huge number to be divided what will i have to use for the division to be accurate long division or some other formula square root or 2 this is to calculate music frequency so the problem will be if we have the big number when i divide it i get always a false answer in the lower register numbers under 1000

i have a big problem understanding which is the right answer in long

divide ) if i divide this number 226991098841700000000000 by multiples of

2 repeatedly till i get to 384.53787890475470178167083368237

answer a = 384.3711364442807442293528752408353

answer b = 421.11364442807442293528752408353

answer c = 384.11364442807442293528752408353

answr d = right answer isnt present

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this post reads like a *Homework* question, not a *Wolfram Language* question. Furthermore, it doesn't explain what is the difficulty of programming the solution.

Comment: Please take a look at `NestList` and `NestWhileList` in the documentation. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good starting point for learning the software called Mathematica. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you use infinite precision arithmetic there will be no errors.

E.g.:

```
226991098841700000000000/2^69
```

[image]

In general a decimal expansion of an accurate number may need an infinite number of decimal digits. This can not be handled by a computer, but, by using `N`, you may specify the number of accurate digits you want. E.g. if you want 35 accurate decimal digits of the number above:

```
N[226991098841700000000000/2^69,35]

(* 384.53787890475470178167083368236945 *)
```